# Using sql queries in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in my foreach loop and I feel I should not be doing this.

How would I go about improving this code(Here I select Messages):

```
try{
    $sql="
    SELECT * FROM messages 
        WHERE workspace_id=:project_id
        ORDER BY message_created DESC
        LIMIT 20 
        OFFSET :offset";
    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':project_id', $project_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $messages=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Now I need users first and last name from table `users`. I couldn't think of another way but putting it in a loop.

```
foreach($messages as $row){ 
echo $row['message'];

$sql=  "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users 
        WHERE user_id=:id 
        LIMIT 1";
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $row['sent_by']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $user=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $user['first_name'] . "&nbsp;" . substr($user['last_name'],0,1) . ".";
}
```

This code works just the way I want it to but it doesn't look like it is supposed to be done this way.

Can anyone help me out here

Comment: Are you trying to get the user associated with the message specifically? If so, we can just do a `join` on the `sent_by` matching the `id` column from users. like this: `LEFT JOIN users on users.id = messages.sent_by`

Comment: Why not just join users onto messages?

Comment: Thanks! Works great! But now I have to list all the columns to select because user has over 30 columns and I just needed two. Well, it's much better to do it this way then the loop

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do a SQL join to completely avoid the foreach loop.

```
  try{
        $sql="
        SELECT messages.*, users.first_name, users.last_name
          FROM messages join users on messages.user_id = users.user_id
            WHERE workspace_id=:project_id
            ORDER BY message_created DESC
            LIMIT 20 
            OFFSET :offset";
        $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':project_id', $project_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $messages=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }catch(Exception $e){echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Note: I am assuming messages table has user id and is stored in "user_id" field. Change the field name accordingly, if it is different.

Comment: Looking at the original code I think the column for user ID in his messages table is called sent_by.  Otherwise this is the correct approach.